# RequestMapping for Spring API not mapping correctly

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a simple web project in eclipse where after launching tomcat I can navigate to a path (specified in @RequestMapping) and do some work.  I have verified that the maven build is correctly compiling my source files but after I start up Tomcat I get a 404 when I navigate to the specified path.  I have included my controller class below as well as my applicationContext and dispatcher-servlet that are in my WEB-INF/ directory.  Can anyone tell what the issue is with the mapping?  I get a 404 while attempting to navigate to all variations of /test

```
@Controller
public class IdGenerator {
@Autowired
private InpoweredIdDAO dao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getId.json",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public InpoweredId getId(@RequestParam String ipAddress, @RequestParam long ts,@RequestParam String agent, 
        @RequestParam String referrer) throws Exception {
    String inpoweredId = InpoweredId.getInpoweredIdFromIp(ipAddress);

    return dao.getImpoweredIdByIpMask(inpoweredId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public void testTomcat() {
    System.out.println("Connected to tomcat");
}
```

application-context.xml

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="inpowered.generator" />

    </beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="inpowered.generator" />

</beans>
```

Edit:
Here is my web.xml it is pretty basic, maybe that is the issue?  I am not getting any stack trace I am just getting a 404

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post your Web.xml file and also the stackTrace, if in case your getting it?

Comment: The `web.xml` should specify the base path to which your request mappings are appended. You are probably just missing the base path, but please post `web.xml` to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `DispatcherServlet` in web.xml

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

So that spring can listen to the url that you are accessing